# The ultimate solution to cross-browser vertical centering?

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, cross-browser

Short and painless, I've tried many ways to get an element, e.g. info text, absolutely centered (H/V) **without** using divs, Javascript, jQuery or whatsoever.

The problem is not getting this to work and there are many different ways, but I'm losing my hair trying to get it cross-browser-compatible.
And it should be so simple.

For example, in the following scenario, FF21 interprets a margin-top of 50% as 100% for no logical reason. (Mobile devices don't, though).

I'm using `<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`

Relevant CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 50% 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle; /* removing this made no real difference at all */
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, MS Sans Serif;
    font-size: 11pt;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: rgb(10, 50, 100);
    color: #ddd;
}
```

**Notes:**

- In Firefox, the expected vertical centering is set with a margin-top of 25% (which looks wrong in mobile browsers, then again).
- Using HTML5
- Trying to **AVOID** any form of script and precalculated, negative margins. The browser is supposed to center properly, as you request it to.

JS-Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sfaVg/

Comment: I **DID** try to set the height of * to 100%, I **DID** play around with vertical-align, I **DID** try padding instead of margin, and many more scenarios. I didn't find **ANY** easy solution that works **EQUAL** in **ALL** common browsers.

Comment: you are trying to center something *without a containing element*? why would you ever need this?

Comment: There is content (text). It doesn't necessarily need to be the body, but I often run into the not satisfacting trouble, that centering something properly needs alot of "playing arround", and then still looks creepy in some browser/screen/os circumstances. For example, 50% should be 50% in all browsers, and not 100% in firefox, just because it's one trick pony and thinks it's made of rainbows and 20% cooler. Yeah... Guess you got my point. Sorry, lol.

Comment: I could encapsulate everything in tons of DIVs to center properly, but that does not seem any close to an "ultimate, clean solution" in any way to me.

Comment: I especially dislike scenarios, where either you or a script have to precalculate the negative margins to get the offsets right. The browser is supposed to just center, as you tell it to.

Comment: I completely agree with you that centering is not straight-forward in css, and is one of its shortcomings. Flexbox might help with this in the future, but is not cross-browser yet. Check out http://dabblet.com/gist/2403795 -- But without a containing element i'm afraid it will stay impossible :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without an element containing the text, i doubt you will be able to position it dead center like you wish. Once you write proper markup (put the paragraph in a `<p>` where it belongs, for instance) it is quite possible though, with the following css;

```
p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Also make sure its container (`body` in your case) gets display: table; and 100% width/height

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/sfaVg/3/

Also, a bonus alternative method (requires two containers) can be found at http://zoffix.com/new/absolute-center-random-width-height.html

A third solution, for when you know the dimensions of what you're centering: http://reisio.com/examples/deadcenter/

Comment: The first solution seems to be exactly what I was looking for, the second looks pretty interestring too. Just wondering, why the display type is required to be `table` in either solutions, but I can life with that, I guess. The third solution is an exact example of what I did **not** want to do. Thanks alot for these.

Comment: @ChrisS.: The reason it needs to render as a `table-cell` is because `vertical-align` behaves differently on table cells (vertically centering its content instead of putting it in the middle of the inline text), see http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/ for more details.